# how to Run VBA code on cell update/change

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

so my code below works for changing activex control command buttons from red to green depending on the value in J1 however J1 value changes.

Now I would like my code to update depending on if J1 have changed. is there a way i can force this to run again after the cell J1 has changed?

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, [J1]) Is Nothing Then
For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
If obj.Name = "CommandButton8" Then
With obj
If [J1].Value >= 1 Then .Object.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
If [J1].Value = 0 Then .Object.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
End If
Next
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: If the change is due to formula recalculation, then you have to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event instead of the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: @BigBen It is, however when I change that to calculate I get "Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: Right. Because `Worksheet_Calculate` has no `Target` parameter.

Comment: @BigBen So do i jut remove the "If not intersect..." or simply the (Target...)? if you could reply as an answer with the code modified this would be extreamly helpful :)

Comment: Since J1 is dependent on A1, couldn't you just use A1 as the target of your code? `If Not Intersect(Target, [A1]) Is Nothing Then` ... You can still use the value of J1 to drive the color of the Activex Objects.

Comment: @basodre sorry I shouldn't have mentioned A1 changes it changes the values in J1 but I just changed it to see and It still didn't update to the corrent color, also A1 is a text value whereas J1 is a number value so doing it by J1 is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `Worksheet_Change` event does not fire when formulas are recalculated. You need to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event for that scenario. The `Calculate` event has no `Target` parameter.
- A blanket `On Error Resume Next` hides all potential errors and is considered bad practice.
- `Me` in a sheet code-behind refers to that sheet and is preferable to `ActiveSheet`.
- You can use the [constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/color-constants) `vbGreen` and `vbRed` instead of the `RGB` function.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    For Each obj In Me.OLEObjects
        If obj.Name = "CommandButton8" Then
           If Me.Range("J1").Value >= 1 Then 
              obj.Object.BackColor = vbGreen
           ElseIf Me.Range("J1").Value = 0 Then 
              obj.Object.BackColor = vbRed
           End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```